# Wordpress custom class to post_thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the below in a Wordpress theme.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'alt'  => 'banner' , 'claass'  => 'header-img')); // show featured image
} 
?>
```

It adds all the attributes as shown, however, when I change the `claass` to `class` to set a custom class, it doesn't show up.

> Before correcting class

```
<img claass="header-img" alt="banner" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/test-image.jpg">
```

> After correcting class

```
<img alt="banner" src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/test-image.jpg">
```

I have no idea why and am stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are checking something else, `class` is the correct attribute. `claass` should not work.

Comment: @Milap I use claass as an example to confirm that the attributes were being added to the IMG tag. It does show up, however when I use class, it doesn't. I realise that class is correct, however, when used it doesn't add it. Thats why I am confused.

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'alt'  => 'banner' , 'class'  => 'alignleft'));` Try this one.

Comment: The same function is working for me please clear cache and check it again 'class' => 'Custom-class' is working perfactly.

Comment: @KushalShah It doesn't work for me. However this is a custom theme. Is there something that is required in functions.php to enable this to work besides add_theme_support(post_thumbnails)

Comment: @Milap Still no good. No class appears in the Img tag at all.

Comment: It seems to me that your theme has some custom filters that remove class attribute. Try checking (in your theme files) if there is "post_thumbnail_html"  or "wp_get_attachment_image_attributes" filter being used. If there are either remove that code or use "remove_filter" function to de-register the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You many need to write below code in your current theme's `functions.php` file,

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html','add_class_to_thumbnail');
function add_class_to_thumbnail($thumb) {
    $thumb = str_replace('attachment-', 'header-img attachment-', $thumb);
    return $thumb;
}
```

Note : I haven't tested above code, its an idea using `post_thumbnail_html` filter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: it is just example filter, you can modify as per your need.